# how do you provide deep mock objects?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I don't think I understand testing as well a should. I have written a lot of tests and gotten decent coverage but I cannot help feeling it has not been intuitive.

Let me explain: if I have a class the I am testing a method and it needs to be passed a big object of some sort, with all kinds of state. This object in turn contains other objects and their states that I know nothing of, how do I create mock or stub objects for this method and give it data that it can work with. It seems I have to create a big object with all kinds of internal sub object information to exercise my method. 
I'm clearly confused!

Comment: You've asked 11 questions and accepted one answer. Help us help you.

Comment: If you need to pass stuff that isn't relevant to what you're testing, then you aren't [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) enough. Also, what @David says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers here are pointing you to mocking frameworks, which you should definitely look at if you're not already using (use Mockito!). However, this is almost certainly an instance of your tests telling you that you've got design problems. If you find yourself having to provide all kinds of unrelated information and mock objects just to make a test pass, then you're

1. trying to test too many pieces at once,
2. writing a test that will be very difficult to read and understand when you're done with it because it's impossible to determine what the test is supposed to be focused on due to a low signal/noise ratio, and/or
3. writing an extremely fragile test that will break on the slightest, unrelated change, incurring high maintenance costs and a "just make the test pass" mentality that doesn't care what the test is supposed to be testing.

These are all symptoms of a system not designed for testability, which almost universally equates to a system not designed for readability, meaning it's not designed well.

If you care about testing well, embrace test-first thinking and TDD. I highly recommend a couple of books on the subject: ["xUnit Test Patterns"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054), which I've read and [reviewed](http://blog.codehangover.com/book-review-xunit-test-patterns/), and ["Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627), which I'm almost finished reading.

Comment: I will look into those books. I would like to be more specific with an example if I may. If I have a mock that is supposed to return some object which itself is a rather stateful thing - for example an order with multiple pieces of information inside it such as the items in it and the items itself having OR mapping data. In such cases would you suggest constructing mocks for even the objects that are returned by my mocked method ? It seems like I have to construct  whole hierarchy of mock objects.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to mock your domain objects, which an Order sounds like. Just use real ones. In fact, some of the value of testing is that it can help you define such objects.

Comment: not sure I understand your comment. My application mainly consists of putting things into say an Order based on some complex rules about what the order contains prior. Each of these items are backed by some unchanging data from the db and some of variables are session state... not sure how I would go about making such an Order available by using mock, when the hierarchy of things is deep and at some point even inaccesible to me (third party code for OR mapping)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a mocking framework. There are many of them. Have a look at either [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/).

In short, you would use code that looks like this:

```
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
when(mockedList.get(1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

Which allows you to specify the behavior when a particular method is called without needing to mock up the entire object. If you have a very complex object, you are mocking, it will be a little more complicated, but you basically just specify the behavior that you are expecting to see used.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with an object with a lot of state and dependent objects that you don't care about it to use a 'nice mock' in EasyMock (the default in Mockito I think). This will always return 'empty' values for any method on your mock object (null, 0 or empty string).

If the dependent objects need to do something then you'll need to return actual or mock objects from your object.

For example, in EasyMock, it will look something like:

```
Mock mock = createNiceMock(MyClass.class);
// override default 'empty' returns for values you care about
// this could return a mock instead
ChildObj c = new ChildObj("state");
expect(mock.getChildObj()).andReturn(c);
// replay, call methods on object under test, verify here
```

But, you probably want to start with the bigger picture: why are you using mocks? Some people prefer testing only with real objects and stubs, while others prefer mocks. Googling 'mocks v. stubs' and reading the top 3 or 4 results will help you decide if mocks are right for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mentioned the mocking lib you are using, I shall suggest what I am using.

However, I haven't tried this feature yet, because it smells bad to me.  Just see if it is really unavoidable:

In [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), you may have a deep stub when creating mock: [Example in official site](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)